# Three.js:right color not picked up

Tags: three.js

I am trying to create a green colored wireframe box. as:

```
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 3, 6, 1 );
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00FF00,wireframe: 
true } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial );
```

But wireframe box only gets white color.
Am I missing some step here?

Comment: Use this as an orientation: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/6166/

Comment: Thanks.It worked.